# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Application template creation error

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I've just installed the VS 2015 and want to start creating Cordova application,
firstly when try to create app I get this error

"The template specified cannot be found. Please check that the full path is correct."

Does anyone got this and solved it ?

Comment: Did you choose the cordova tools during the installation of vs 2015 Community RC?  As I remember the default is Not to install Cordova.

Comment: Hey DjBuddy, thanks for using VS 2015 for your Cordova app development. I have a few questions for you - 1) Can you see the Cordova blank template? (2) If so, where are you trying to create the project?  you might be seeing this error if the location of the project is too long or has some hidden ascii characters. Can you try creating the project at the root or a temp directory under c:\ and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @SubhagOak I tried but same result

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Start,
2. click Control Panel,
3. and then click Programs.
4. Click Programs and Features
5. and then select the Visual Studio Edition you installed.
6. Click or right click and select Uninstall/Change.
7. In the setup wizard, select modify and then click Next.
8. You will see a list of extras to install.
9. Find the mobile tools and cross development tools. I can't remember what they are all called but you will know what you want when you see them there's quite a few options for mobile development .
   10.Then proceed to install the missing packages that you need.
10. It takes quite a while for them to install
11. You will then be able to start a project like you tried to before